# Options available for different lists

Tags: wss-3.0, list

Following on from my discovery that the Visio option is only available on machines that have Visio installed i found another oddity.

I have two lists, one is just a regular "Tasks" and the other is a "Project Tasks".

In the Task list I am able to see the "create visio diagram" option (and it works) but in the Project Tasks the option is not there.  Both lists allow me to export to Excel or open in Access.

Is there a property somewhere that will allow me to create Visio from a Project Task list?

Comment: I've been looking at the source code and the aspx files that are in SharePoint Designer all have the Create Visio Diagram option but when I view them in a browswer there seems to be some extra code appearing from somewhere.

In the case of the regular list, the Javascript code:

var diagramButtonAppName = GetDiagramLaunchInstalled();
var diagramBtnText = 'Create ' + diagramButtonAppName + ' Diagram' ;


This then seems to feed the code in the aspx to present the menu option, but it is not in the Project Tasks List which uses exactly the same master page and..!

I am very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the Actions menu from SharePoint is based on the list type. You can see the list type by viewing the rendered source and looking at the JavaScript section that declare ctx (context) variables. There is a list on MSDN that tells what this is. The workaround I have used is to write JavaScript code to add the menu option at runtime or you can create custom actions as a feature since this menu is generated by the SharePoint DLLs.

Comment: Can you share the code and some instructions on where exactly to put it?  

Maybe a link to the MSDN articel as well?

Thanks!